# jquery ui datepicker doesn't disappear in IE7 after selection

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, datepicker

Got the jQuery UI datepicker plugin working wonderfully, however, when using IE7, the calendar doesn't fade away after you make a selection like it does in FF, Safari, etc.

Here's the URL http://www.mchenry.edu/insideApp/OIRPprojectrequest/oirpprojectrequestform.aspx

I hope it's something silly, 'cuz IE7 is the only browser I need to support for internal clients.

Thnx!

EDIT: Try this URL, http://www.mchenry.edu/test/oirpprojectrequestform.aspx

Sorry 'bout that!

Comment: cannot access that URL - HTTP Error 403.6 - Forbidden: IP address of the client has been rejected.

Comment: You are not authorized to view this page

Comment: can you copy the relevant code onto http://jsbin.com ?

Comment: works fine on my ie8 with compatibility mode on

Comment: Um, the calendar doesn't fade away when I view it in IE8, compatibility mode or not. Hmm...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Webpage error details
>
> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;
>   MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0;
>   .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR
>   3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729) Timestamp: Mon, 21 Sep 2009 18:50:51
>   UTC
>
> Message: 'length' is null or not an
>   object Line: 139 Char: 17 Code: 0 URI:
>   http://www.mchenry.edu/aspnet_client/system_web/1_1_4322/WebUIValidation.js

`event.srcElement.Validators` is `undefined` when i step through with IE8. Do you mean to be accessing `Validators` on the `DispHTMLAnchorElement`?

Comment: I am using the validation plugin here as well. Do you think it may be a conflict between the two? Unless it's an easy fix, I may have to ditch one or the other. Not sure how important the client-side validation is, since it's an internal app and we have server-side checks as well. Hmm...

Comment: Clarification: I am using the jQuery validation plugin - our backend .Net guru wants to use .Net validation juice on this but I disabled her trickery.

Comment: well validation should be on the form element; here it was being performed on an anchor, the event source.

Answer (score 1):

If you have something like this in your datepicker setup:

onSelect: function(){ this.focus(); }
onClose: function(){ this.focus(); }

This causes the element to be given focus, and thus validated by the validator plugin.

Unfortunately, in IE7, this causes a bug as the focus event is called twice and the datepicker gets confused and pops up again.

The solution is not to call the validator explicitly on the element, then move the focus to the next element for IE to preserve the tab order.

```
                onSelect: function () {
                    var elementCounter, input, form;
                    input = $(this);
                    form = input.parents('form:first');

                    // validate the selected date
                    form.validate().element(this);

                    if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version < 8) {
                       // MSIE 7 triggers focus event twice, forcing the datepicker to re-open
                       // to get around this, we move the focus to the next form element

                       for (var elementCounter = 0; elementCounter < form[0].elements.length; elementCounter++){
                           if (form[0].elements[elementCounter].name == input.attr('name')) {
                               $(form[0].elements[elementCounter+1]).focus();
                               break;
                           }
                       }
                    } else {
                       // give focus back to the input element to preserve tabbing
                       $(this).trigger('focus');
                    }
                },
                onClose: function () {

                    // validate the selected date
                    $(this).parents('form:first').validate().element(this);

                }
```

Comment: I got a nullref error on `form[0]` when I ran this code in IE9/IE7mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you specify the tabindex attribute on your input fields, then this might work well for you:

```
onClose: function() {
    $('input[tabindex="' + ($(this).attr('tabindex') + 1) + '"]').focus();
}
```